# Pulling from Git by PHP and Console

Tags: php, git

I have a repository for project which is on Bitbucket. I clone the repo to my local PC to work on it. Then I push back to Bitbucket, and then I connect with putty to my server and call

```
git pull
```

And pull the changes to the live server. I never push from my server. Everything works fine like this, but its not very convenient to connect through putty to server in order to pull. I made small script "git_pull_script.sh" in where is something like:

```
git reset --hard
git clean -f
git pull
chown -f -R tdadmin *
...
```

Nothing problematic there. If I run the script on server

```
bash /home/tdadmin/git_pull_script.sh
```

Everything goes well and does what I need. Just to clarify, git_pull_script has set owner and group tdadmin.

Now in order to make it simpler for me, I wrote this tiny php script.

```
<?php
exec('bash /home/tdadmin/git_pull_script.sh', $output);
print_r($output);
```

which I think should do the work. So I could simply call http://tddomain.com/pullscript.php

Unfortunately that does not work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you allowed to use exec() in your php.ini and are you getting any errors in your logs?

Comment: I am allowed to use exec() , the logs let me check, Its quite hard to find them, I compalained about this already many times to my provider, no success...

Comment: As a test to see if git_pull_script is executing, put an echo "I got here" as the first line. You should check the return code.  See the exec docs.

Comment: It is possible your git pull script is executing as a different user and can't authenticate to the Git repository. When executed under php your ssh agent forwarding will not be active.

Comment: @walrii Thats exactly what I thought, but the domain user is tdadmin and I changed owner and group to tdadmin, so it should be fine I think

Comment: Found the log, it says "[Mon Sep 03 02:53:40 2012] [error] [client 1.202.22.225] fatal: Unable to create '/home/tdadmin/.../.git/index.lock': Permission denied" I will try to find it and change permissions

Comment: Just because the script has the right permissions, it does not mean that the web server's user can modify your files.

Comment: Changed owner and group of .git directory and it works. Thank you, I should have check the logs first. sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the file system rights. Even though  have changed all permissions, ".git" repository folder stayed with root owner and group. Once I changed that, everything works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps bash cannot be found? Here is a simpler test script to narrow that down

```
<?php
$output=array();
exec("bash --version",$output);
echo "bash:\n";print_r($output);
$output=array();
exec("/bin/bash --version",$output);
echo "/bin/bash:\n";print_r($output);
?>
```

Another idea: if your host is using chroot, or something, maybe /home/tdadmin cannot be found? Try a script to confirm that:

```
<?php
echo file_exists('/home/tdadmin/git_pull_script.sh')?"Yes":"no";
?>
```